# nth-of-type select the first 3 elements with a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select the first three or four items with the class `.class-b`

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="class-a">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-a">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-b">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-b">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-b">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-b">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-b">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-b">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-c">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-c">xxx</div>
  <div class="class-c">xxx</div>
</div>
```

The amount of `div`s will vary.

Comment: The is no nth-of class selector so ..not possible. JQuery would be your answer.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-select-items-specific-class/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class?rq=1

Comment: If the *order* of these elements will not vary you *could* abuse sibling selectors, but the more elements you need the more verbose your selector will be.

Comment: The order will vary... See this: http://jsfiddle.net/A2V8T/

Comment: So for example you might have .class-a + .class-b + .class-a + .class-b (where such a selector would then break spectacularly)?

Comment: @BoltClock - I always thought examples like the fiddle the OP posted shouldn't work with nth-of-type based on a class, but it seems to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: @j08691: They are the nth elements of their type, which is div. In this case, since they're all divs, it's functionally equivalent to :nth-child(). The class selector just limits matches to elements of that particular class, rather than directly affect how :nth-of-type() counts elements.

Comment: @BoltClock - Ah so it's the order of the example that's throwing me off. If they weren't in order it wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: @j08691: You're not alone.

Answer (score 4):

`nth-of-type` targets the type tag (div, span, a...) and it can't target `nth` elements  that has a specific class. You can read more about this selector on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type).

If your elements don't always have the same order as in your example, you will need JS :

---

**JS solution :**

Here is a quick jQuery snippet that selects the 3 first elements with the class `.class-b` and adds the `.selected` class to them. You can then use it to style targeted elements.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/RG38t/)**

*jQuery :*

```
var child_num = 0;
$('.wrapper > .class-b').each(function(){
    if(child_num < 3){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    child_num++;
});
```

*CSS :*

```
.selected{
    background:gold;
}
```

Comment: Thx, but jQuery is no option

Comment: @user3661304 well as the order and number of elements can change, `nth-of-type()` won't work for you and I don't think you will find a CSS solution. How are you generating the layout? couldn't you assign a specific class to the targeted elements during the layout generation?

Comment: No, im not generating the layout so it has to be flexible. But there is definitly no way to do this :-(

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with only CSS, *however*, it relies on the elements staying as groups of siblings otherwise it may not work as expected.

```
.class-a + .class-b
```

will select only the first, then use

```
.class-a + .class-b + .class-b
```

for the second, and so on..

I made a jsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KpLMR/

Comment: Yes, basically what I said in the comments. The only catch is that it assumes the elements are in the exact order given. But if it works for the OP, it's an answer.

Comment: I was just reading your comments after posting this. It's a good point and I will put it in the answer. When he said that the order *does change* he gave an example which the order hadn't changed so that kinda confused me..

Comment: Yeah... you're not the only one. Not sure if he just misunderstood my comment.

Comment: unfortunetly this is not working for me. I have to use just one selector to do this.